# complex polynomial on the unit disc

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I have the following problem:

Let $z_1,...,z_n$ be complex numbers such that $|z_i|=1, \forall i$. Prove that there exists $z\in \mathbb{C}$ with $|z|=1$ such that $|(z-z_1)(z-z_2)\cdot ...\cdot (z-z_n)|\geq 2$.

I could only prove that the bound is 1, using maximum modulus theorem, but I don't have any idea to prove the desired bound.

If you can help me, I'll be very grateful with you.

Comment: (would expect this to be a duplicate so as a hint) If $f(z)=(z-z_1)(z-z_2)\cdot ...\cdot (z-z_n)=z^n+a_1z^{n-1}+a_n$ and $\omega^n=1$ is a primitive root of unity of order $n$, then show that $f(z)+f(\omega z)+..f(\omega^{n-1}z)=nz^n+na_n$ with $|a_n|=1$ and show that choosing the right $|z_0|=1$ gives $|f(z_0)+f(\omega z_0)+..f(\omega^{n-1}z_0)|=2n$ so conclude

Comment: wow, great solution!